# convergence on sequences using cauchy's criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence

$$x_{n+1}=\frac12\left(x_n+\frac2{x_n}\right),~n>1,~x_1=1$$

How can I prove the sequence is Cauchy, and get the limit?

Comment: Are you sure the sequence is: $ x_n= (\frac{1}{2})(x_n +\frac{x_n}{2})$ and isn't $ x_{n+2}= (\frac{1}{2})(x_{n+1} +\frac{x_n}{2})$?

Comment: i verified that the sequence is $x_(n+1)=(1/2)(x_n +2/x_n)$

Comment: That's very different. I edited it for you — is this what you meant?

Comment: Awesome. Mille merci

Answer (score 1):

Once you have shown that the sequence is convergent then by the given recursive relation it not hard to find the limit. Just take the limit as $n\longrightarrow \infty$ in both sides and you will get that limit should be $1$. So, it is enough to show that the given sequence is convergent. First note that $x_n\geq 0$ for all $n$. So, if we show that $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence then we will be done, because any decreasing sequence which is bounded below is convergent. Let us now show this
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} - x_n &= \frac{1}{2x_n}(x_n^2 +2)-x_n\\
&=\frac{2-x_n^2}{2x_n}\\
&=\frac{2-\frac{1}{4x_{n-1}^2}(x_{n-1}^2+2)^2}{\frac{x_{n-1}^2+2}{x_{n-1}}}\\
&= -\frac{x_{n-1}^4+4-x_{n-1}^2}{4x_{n-1}(x_{n-1}^2+2)}\\
&= -\frac{(x_{n-1}^2-2)^2}{4x_{n-1}(x_{n-1}^2+2)}\\
&\leq 0.
\end{align}
Therefore, $x_{n+1}\leq x_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: never mind!!! Happy to help.....:)